# Vue: How to merge object props with default values

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-props

I want to set an object `title` as a prop with `type` and `text` inside. As a default, I want to set only the default value for `type` to be `h2`.

When `title: {text: 'Some text'}` is passed as props, I want to merge it with the default values so the result would be `title: {type: 'h2', text: 'Some text'}`.

How can I achieve this? Using Object.assign can be used but I'm not sure how in this case.

```
export interface Props {
  title: {
    type: 'h1' | 'h2'
    text: string
  }
}

withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  title: () => {
    return {
      type: 'h2',
      text: null,
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a computed like that

```
export interface Props {
  title: {
    type: 'h1' | 'h2'
    text: string
  }
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()

const preparedTitle = computed(() => ({
  type: 'h1',
  ...props.title
}))
```

Another way is to make titleType and titleText separate props

```
export interface Props {
  titleType: 'h1' | 'h2'
  titleText: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  titleType: 'h1'
})

// You can optionally merge them back if you really need to
const title = computed(() => ({
  type: props.titleType,
  text: props.titleText,
}))
```